# Does Php-fpm can process a cli script? What is happening inside official docker php?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, composer-php, docker-entrypoint

I am using official Docker Php-fpm (https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.2/alpine3.8/fpm/Dockerfile) and official Nginx Image for my php website. I have configured Nginx to talk to php-fpm over port 9000. The entrypoint of the docker is given below.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- php-fpm "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

You can see when we try to execute a command like `docker exec -it container whoami`, it is prefixed with `php-fpm`.

So my question is when I pass a PHP cli script like e.g `docker exec -it container composer install` how it is interpreted ? does `composer install` processed by php-fpm or php-cli (/usr/local/bin/php) ?

As per my knowledge composer is a cli script which I install like below should be processed by php-cli.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin -- --filename=composer
```

Comment: It will use the CLI SAPI.

Comment: Is Php-fpm clever enough to pass the script to CLI Sapi when it detects it as command line script otherwise pass it to CGI sapi?

Comment: What? Why would it? It runs where you tell it to run. If you send something to FPM it will run in FPM, it won't randomly hand over to a different SAPI.

Comment: Check the entrypoint please. It always prefix `php-fpm` with any command you pass e.g if you pass `composer install` it turns to something like  `php-fpm composer install` .

Comment: `docker exec` ignores the entrypoint (script or otherwise).  It’s only used on the initial `docker run`.  You might consider finding a way to do whatever task is involved here without using it, though; it’s really useful for debugging but not a great idea as part of the core workflow.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze . I think I got it now. So `exec "$@"` only executes the command that is passed as CMD in Dockerfile i.e here `CMD ["php-fpm"]`  . Command from `docker exec` doesn't override that CMD["php-fpm"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec "$@"` only executes the command that is defined as CMD in Dockerfile/Docker-compose file only once when the container is created initially. Once the container starts and you want to run any command on it then that command from `docker exec` doesn't override that CMD["php-fpm"]

Also composer script uses php-cli not php-fpm. 
https://github.com/dbjpanda/composer/blob/70557f3ab7b84a896179396509611fae66b19773/bin/composer#L4